# No sound output device recognized by PulseAudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 18.10

I'm setting up Ubuntu 18.10 one step at a time on my Jumper EZPad Mini 3, a cheap Chinese Windows tablet. Now I'm trying to get audio to work - just headphone jack output working is enough for me (no need for speakers).

The tablet uses a ES8316 codec, which the kernel seemingly already has support for, as its kernel module loads alright:

```
[    7.686752] bytcht_es8316 bytcht_es8316: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> media-cpu-dai mapping ok
[    7.686856] bytcht_es8316 bytcht_es8316: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> deepbuffer-cpu-dai mapping ok
[    7.689502] bytcht_es8316 bytcht_es8316: ES8316 HiFi <-> ssp2-port mapping ok
```

In its current state, the tablet lists only a Dummy Output in Settings. PulseAudio doesn't seem to see the card, listing only HDMI output (which I don't plan to use):

```
~$ pacmd list-cards
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_02.0-platform-hdmi-lpe-audio>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hdmi_lpe_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:02.0-platform-hdmi-lpe-audio"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/hdmi-lpe-audio/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "22b0"
        device.product.name = "Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

However, ALSA seems to acknowledge the card just fine:

```
~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Audio          ]: HdmiLpeAudio - Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
                      Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
 1 [bytchtes8316   ]: bytcht-es8316 - bytcht-es8316
                      Insyde-CherryTrail

~$ aplay -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=Audio
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Default Audio Device
hdmi:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=bytchtes8316
    bytcht-es8316, 
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=bytchtes8316,DEV=0
    bytcht-es8316, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=bytchtes8316,DEV=1
    bytcht-es8316, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=bytchtes8316,DEV=0
    bytcht-es8316, 
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=bytchtes8316,DEV=1
    bytcht-es8316, 
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=bytchtes8316,DEV=0
    bytcht-es8316, 
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=bytchtes8316,DEV=1
    bytcht-es8316, 
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=bytchtes8316,DEV=0
    bytcht-es8316, 
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=bytchtes8316,DEV=1
    bytcht-es8316, 
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

But then again, if I try to manually assign a card to play a wav file, `aplay` errors out:

```
~$ aplay -D hw:CARD=bytchtes8316,DEV=0 ./wz/01-10.wav 
Playing WAVE './wz/01-10.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1345: Channels count non available

~$ aplay -D plughw:CARD=bytchtes8316,DEV=0 ./wz/01-10.wav 
Playing WAVE './wz/01-10.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1403: Unable to install hw params:
ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  S16_LE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: 16
FRAME_BITS: 16
CHANNELS: 1
RATE: 16000
PERIOD_TIME: 125000
PERIOD_SIZE: 2000
PERIOD_BYTES: 4000
PERIODS: 4
BUFFER_TIME: 500000
BUFFER_SIZE: 8000
BUFFER_BYTES: 16000
TICK_TIME: 0
```

I've read a bunch of other answers and tried the usual restarting ALSA/PA, clearing/rebuilding PA config, even purging and reinstalling ALSA/PA, but nothing changed.

EDIT: I should also note that connecting Bluetooth headphones will result in PA seeing a new BT card, and also being able to output audio (albeit with heavy stutter, but that's outside the scope here). To me this means PA actually works alright, I just need to make it see the card somehow.

**What can I do at this point?**

---

For reference, here's the full output of `pacmd info`, if it's of any use:

```
~$ pacmd info
Memory blocks currently allocated: 1, size: 63.9 KiB.
Memory blocks allocated during the whole lifetime: 102, size: 3.0 MiB.
Memory blocks imported from other processes: 0, size: 0 B.
Memory blocks exported to other processes: 0, size: 0 B.
Total sample cache size: 0 B.
Default sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default channel map: front-left,front-right
Default sink name: auto_null
Default source name: auto_null.monitor
Memory blocks of type POOL: 1 allocated/85 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type POOL_EXTERNAL: 0 allocated/0 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type APPENDED: 0 allocated/0 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type USER: 0 allocated/0 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type FIXED: 0 allocated/0 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type IMPORTED: 0 allocated/17 accumulated.
27 module(s) loaded.
    index: 0
    name: <module-device-restore>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute state of devices"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 1
    name: <module-stream-restore>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute/device state of streams"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 2
    name: <module-card-restore>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore profile of cards"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 3
    name: <module-augment-properties>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Augment the property sets of streams with additional static information"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 4
    name: <module-switch-on-port-available>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "David Henningsson"
        module.description = "Switches ports and profiles when devices are plugged/unplugged"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 5
    name: <module-switch-on-connect>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Michael Terry"
        module.description = "When a sink/source is added, switch to it or conditionally switch to it"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 6
    name: <module-udev-detect>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Detect available audio hardware and load matching drivers"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 7
    name: <module-alsa-card>
    argument: <device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_02.0-platform-hdmi-lpe-audio" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_02.0-platform-hdmi-lpe-audio" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1">
    used: 0
    load once: no
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ALSA Card"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 9
    name: <module-bluetooth-policy>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Frédéric Dalleau, Pali Rohár"
        module.description = "Policy module to make using bluetooth devices out-of-the-box easier"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 10
    name: <module-bluetooth-discover>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available Bluetooth daemon and load the corresponding discovery module"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 11
    name: <module-bluez5-discover>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio devices and load BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio drivers"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 12
    name: <module-native-protocol-unix>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: no
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Native protocol (UNIX sockets)"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 13
    name: <module-gsettings>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Sylvain Baubeau"
        module.description = "GSettings Adapter"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 14
    name: <module-default-device-restore>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the default sink and source"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 15
    name: <module-rescue-streams>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "When a sink/source is removed, try to move its streams to the default sink/source"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 16
    name: <module-always-sink>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Always keeps at least one sink loaded even if it's a null one"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 17
    name: <module-null-sink>
    argument: <sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'>
    used: 0
    load once: no
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Clocked NULL sink"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 18
    name: <module-intended-roles>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically set device of streams based on intended roles of devices"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 19
    name: <module-suspend-on-idle>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "When a sink/source is idle for too long, suspend it"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 20
    name: <module-console-kit>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Create a client for each ConsoleKit session of this user"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 21
    name: <module-systemd-login>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Create a client for each login session of this user"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 22
    name: <module-position-event-sounds>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Position event sounds between L and R depending on the position on screen of the widget triggering them."
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 23
    name: <module-role-cork>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Mute & cork streams with certain roles while others exist"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 24
    name: <module-snap-policy>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Canonical Ltd"
        module.description = "Ubuntu Snap policy management"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 25
    name: <module-filter-heuristics>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Detect when various filters are desirable"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 26
    name: <module-filter-apply>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Load filter sinks automatically when needed"
        module.version = "12.2"
    index: 44
    name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: no
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Command line interface protocol (UNIX sockets)"
        module.version = "12.2"
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 344 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 17
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
1 source(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null.monitor>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    module: 17
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Dummy Output"
        device.class = "monitor"
        device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
8 client(s) logged in.
    index: 0
    driver: <module-systemd-login.c>
    owner module: 21
    properties:
        application.name = "Login Session c2"
        systemd-login.session = "c2"
    index: 1
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 12
    properties:
        application.name = "unity-panel-service"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        window.x11.screen = "0"
        application.process.id = "1764"
        application.process.user = "crossgate"
        application.process.host = "EZPM3"
        application.process.binary = "unity-panel-service"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "998f9a12ea834827856eacfaeedd2dc7"
    index: 2
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 12
    properties:
        application.name = "Terminal"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        application.icon_name = "utilities-terminal"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        window.x11.screen = "0"
        application.process.id = "2050"
        application.process.user = "crossgate"
        application.process.host = "EZPM3"
        application.process.binary = "gnome-terminal-server"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "998f9a12ea834827856eacfaeedd2dc7"
    index: 3
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 12
    properties:
        application.name = "Ubuntu Audio Settings"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        application.id = "com.canonical.settings.sound"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = "0.1"
        application.process.id = "1593"
        application.process.user = "crossgate"
        application.process.host = "EZPM3"
        application.process.binary = "indicator-sound-service"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "998f9a12ea834827856eacfaeedd2dc7"
    index: 4
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 12
    properties:
        application.name = "Ubuntu Audio Settings"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        application.id = "com.canonical.settings.sound"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = "0.1"
        application.process.id = "1593"
        application.process.user = "crossgate"
        application.process.host = "EZPM3"
        application.process.binary = "indicator-sound-service"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "998f9a12ea834827856eacfaeedd2dc7"
    index: 7
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 12
    properties:
        application.name = "GNOME Volume Control Media Keys"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = "1.0"
        application.process.id = "1592"
        application.process.user = "crossgate"
        application.process.host = "EZPM3"
        application.process.binary = "unity-settings-daemon"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "998f9a12ea834827856eacfaeedd2dc7"
    index: 16
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 12
    properties:
        application.name = "Chrome input"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        application.process.id = "3407"
        application.process.user = "crossgate"
        application.process.host = "EZPM3"
        application.process.binary = "chrome"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "998f9a12ea834827856eacfaeedd2dc7"
    index: 22
    driver: <cli.c>
    owner module: 44
    properties:
        application.name = "UNIX socket client"
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_02.0-platform-hdmi-lpe-audio>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hdmi_lpe_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:02.0-platform-hdmi-lpe-audio"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/hdmi-lpe-audio/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "22b0"
        device.product.name = "Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
0 sink input(s) available.
0 source output(s) available.
0 cache entrie(s) available.
```

Comment: have you tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085174/no-sound-after-upgrade-to-18-10-only-a-dummy-device-is-shown/1085992#1085992 already? Seems to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/timidity/+bug/1793640

Comment: @user1798382 Just checked, `timidity-daemon` is not installed on this device in the first place.